# IntelliSense stuck in updating

Tags: visual-studio-code, gcc, syntax-highlighting

After the latest c/c++ extension update  (v1.10.5) for vs code, I'm having problems with Intellisense highlighting my c code. It does not highlight syntax/give suggestions most of the time. Also there's a little flame icon at the bottom of the vscode (status bar) telling me " Updating Intellisense" but hasn't gone away since the update! I'm using gcc for creating/compiling my code, maybe that's the problem??
idk just want the good old syntax highlighting back :/ any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if you're still having problems with IntelliSense, but I have been having trouble with it connecting to a remote SSH host recently. The 'best' answer I have been able to find, although tedious and not a *good* solution, is to uninstall the C/C++ extension from both my local machine and the remote machine and then exit VS Code, and then open VS Code and reinstall. I know it is not ideal, but until I find a better way or a complete fix, it's what I have been doing. I'll let you know about any updates though!